# How to create rows based on one column values comma seperated

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Begin tran

create table #user_det 
             (user_id varchar(50), emp_id int, role varchar(500))

insert into #user_det (user_id , emp_id , role)
select 'Sankar', 431544 , '(Developer),(DBA),(Designer)'
union all
select 'Gowri', 145721 , '(DBA),(Designer)'
union all
select 'Raja', 101010 , 'ALL'

select * from #user_det

drop table #user_det

Rollback




OutPut Required:
===============

select 'Sankar' as user_id ,431544 as emp_id ,'Developer' as Role
union all
select 'Sankar' as user_id ,431544 as emp_id ,'DBA' as Role
union all
select 'Sankar' as user_id ,431544 as emp_id ,'Designer' as Role
union all
select 'Gowri' as user_id ,145721 as emp_id ,'DBA' as Role
union all
select 'Gowri' as user_id ,145721 as emp_id ,'Designer' as Role
union all
select 'Raja' as user_id ,101010 as emp_id ,'ALL' as Role
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone should have a good split/parse function as SqlZim linked to.

Here is another option if you don't want or can't use a UDF

```
Select A.user_id
      ,A.emp_id
      ,[role]    = Replace(Replace(B.RetVal,')',''),'(','')
 From #user_det A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.[Role],',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016+ you can use `string_split()`.

In SQL Server pre-2016, using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
select user_id, emp_id, Role = replace(replace(s.Item,'(',''),')','')
from #user_det u
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(u.role,',') s
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YVXGU42109

returns:

```
+---------+--------+-----------+
| user_id | emp_id |   Role    |
+---------+--------+-----------+
| Sankar  | 431544 | Developer |
| Sankar  | 431544 | DBA       |
| Sankar  | 431544 | Designer  |
| Gowri   | 145721 | DBA       |
| Gowri   | 145721 | Designer  |
| Raja    | 101010 | ALL       |
+---------+--------+-----------+
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

`delimitedsplit8K` function by Jeff Moden:

```
create function [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (
      @pstring varchar(8000)
    , @pdelimiter char(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
 return
  with e1(N) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(N) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(N) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , ctetally(N) as (
    select top (isnull(datalength(@pstring),0)) 
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4
  )
  , ctestart(N1) as (
    select 1 union all
    select t.N+1 from ctetally t where substring(@pstring,t.N,1) = @pdelimiter
  )
  , ctelen(N1,L1) as (
    select s.N1,
      isnull(nullif(charindex(@pdelimiter,@pstring,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
    from ctestart s
  )
 select itemnumber = row_number() over(order by l.N1)
      , item       = substring(@pstring, l.N1, l.L1)
   from ctelen l
;
go
```

Comment: Hi SqlZim Thanks for your answer. But I need this in SQL server 2012 version. Can you please help me

Comment: @SankarM This works on sql server 2012. The note was for an alternative if you were on 2016.

Comment: Ok Got it. Thank you. Any chances to write in a single query with out using that function ?

Comment: @SankarM For that you should use [the answer by John Cappelletti](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43255805/2333499)